# How can I transition this font awesome (v5.0) color from white to my custom color?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

I am just working on a beginner project, and when I hover over the Instagram Icon, I would like it to slowly transition to the gradient of colors from some svg code I copied off of StackOverflow. I understand how the SVG code works (generally), but cannot figure out how to make the transitions work.

Here's a snippet of necessary code, along with the css that I've tried so far.

I believe the end transition value for `fill` is what is causing the issue. If I change it to a different value, like `"blue"`, or `"red"`, the transition works fine.

```css
.social-container {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid white;
 display: flex;
 width: 150px;
 height: 35px;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}


svg {
 transition: fill 3s ease;
}

.instagram-logo svg * {
  transition: all 2s ease;
 fill: black;
}

.instagram-logo:hover svg * {
 fill: url(#rg);
}

/* So I noticed the issue is the .instagram-logo:hover svg * {}. When I use a solid color like "blue" for the fill value, the transition works flawlessly. But when using the url, it doesn't work at all */
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="instagram-logo">
  <svg width="0" height="0">
    <radialGradient id="rg" r="150%" cx="30%" cy="107%">
      <stop stop-color="#fdf497" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="#fdf497" offset="0.05" />
      <stop stop-color="#fd5949" offset="0.45" />
      <stop stop-color="#d6249f" offset="0.6" />
      <stop stop-color="#285AEB" offset="0.9" />
    </radialGradient>
  </svg>
  <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers started to support CSS transition of `<color>` values, so they do accept to make the transition between your CSS `fill: <color>` to an other `fill: <color>`.

**But**, when you are setting this CSS `fill` value to the gradient, for the engine, it's now an `<urlFunc>` value, which eventually resolves to an `<image>` value*. So transitioning from a `<color>` to this new value is not possible.

*<sup>Though I'm not sure about this assertion...</sup>

---

One solution though would be to animate a CSS [`<filter>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) value:

```css
.instagram-logo{
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
.instagram-logo svg.fa-instagram path{
  fill: url(#rg);
}

/* from black to color */
.instagram-logo svg.fa-instagram{
  filter: brightness(0%) grayscale(100%);
  transition: filter 2s ease, -webkit-filter 2s ease;
}
.instagram-logo svg.fa-instagram:hover{
  filter: brightness(100%) grayscale(0%);
}

/* from white to color */
.instagram-logo.white{
  background: black;
}
.instagram-logo.white svg.fa-instagram{
  filter: brightness(0%) grayscale(100%) invert(1);
}
.instagram-logo.white svg.fa-instagram:hover{
  /*
    we need to make a new declaration
    because transitions can only be done on func values 
    so we need the same <filterFunc> at both hands of the transition
 */
  filter: brightness(100%) grayscale(0%) invert(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="instagram-logo">
  <svg class="hidden" width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1">
    <radialGradient id="rg" r="150%" cx="30%" cy="107%">
      <stop stop-color="#fdf497" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="#fdf497" offset="0.05" />
      <stop stop-color="#fd5949" offset="0.45" />
      <stop stop-color="#d6249f" offset="0.6" />
      <stop stop-color="#285AEB" offset="0.9" />
    </radialGradient>
  </svg>
  <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>

</div>
<div class="instagram-logo white">
  <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```

Note that in given example, I set the filter on the parent `<svg>` node, because chrome doesn't seem to support CSS filtering on inner SVG nodes without prefix yet.